# Drupal 8: when I enter a Clean URL, it converts to node format in the URL. How to show the clean URL and not the node URL?

Tags: 8, uri

What could be causing a switch to show the node in the URL rather than the alias? When I type in the clean URL rather than the node, the browser goes to the page just fine. It just shows the node in the URL.  rewrite_module seems to be installed as it is shown when I use httpd -M. My .htaccess file is the same as the head of Drupal. I am running Centos7. In my apache conf file,  have AllowOverride All for the location that my .htaccess file is in.

Comment: try with  url alias

Comment: what do you mean? like www.example.com/funpage    ?

Comment: yeah for eg:   /downloads   to /node/add/download_form

Comment: when I put in a page like /downloads it turns into /node/67 for example.

Comment: Did you get it listed on the url alias list (admin/config/search/path)?

Comment: oh I see what you mean. This list shows clean URLs and not pages like /node/67

Comment: wait alias doesn't list node, but it does under system